# Automate wbemtest with pywinauto

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

Having trouble automating some steps via pywinauto.
It seems to not be able to open wbemtest (the process that needs automation).

My code is generated with SWAPY:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\wbemtest.exe" ')
window = app.Dialog
window.Wait('ready')
button = window.Button
button.Click()
window2 = app.Dialog
edit = window2.Edit
edit.ClickInput()
edit.Select()
edit.DoubleClickInput('\securitycenter2')
button2 = window.Button7
button2.Click()
window3 = app.Dialog
edit2 = window3.Edit
edit2.ClickInput('\antivirusproduct')
button3 = window3.OK
button3.Click()
```

The problem is that it seems to work with other applications (tested on potplayer), but with wbemtest I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 992, in start
    start_info)             # STARTUPINFO structure.
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vali/PycharmProjects/untitled/wsc.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\wbemtest.exe" ')
  File "C:\Users\Vali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 997, in start
    raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process ""C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemtest.exe" "
Error returned by CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Comment: the issue seems to carry on to any executable inside windows folder. python just won't have it...

Comment: I even tried subprocess and while i can get some of the executables in windows folder to open wbemtest.exe is still a no go, this time without any error...
`import subprocess
wsc = "cmd.exe /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\wbemtest.exe"
subprocess.Popen(wsc, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: got to the bottom of it.

Comment: Are you able to run it manually in `cmd.exe`? With single backslashes, of course. Double slashes are needed for Python only.

Comment: the problem was that I was using python x86 version on 64-bit windows. had to switch wbem for sysnative to get it going

Comment: Can you post it as an answer and mark as accepted? It doesn’t matter you’re an author of question. I just take about pywinauto tag statistics. Thanks!

Comment: Posting your own answer or accepting other’s answers is considered polite on StackOverflow. Otherwise chances to get help are decreasing in a long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was that I was using python x86 version on 64-bit windows. had to switch wbem for sysnative to get it going